# Decomposing $Y=U_1+U_2$ so that $\operatorname{Cov}(U_1,X\mid Z)=0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(U_2,X\mid Z)=\operatorname{Cov}(U_2,X)$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be random variables.

- Is it always possible to decompose $Y=U_1+U_2$ such that $\operatorname{Cov}(U_1,X\mid Z)=0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(U_2,X\mid Z)=\operatorname{Cov}(U_2,X)$ i.e. the first term and $X$ are uncorrelated conditional on $Z$ and the second term and $X$ can be correlated independently of $Z$? I don't need explicit expressions for $U_1$ or $U_2$.
- Can the covariances be replaced with independence (i.e. $U_1 \perp X\mid Z$ and $(U_2,X) \perp Z$)?
- Are there any similar results?
- What if $Y$ were replaced with $g(Y)=U_1+U_2$ for some function $g$?

I am interested in methods of how to go about solving such a problem and references. Thanks.

Comment: See book 
W. J. Krzanowski, Principles of Multivariate Analysis. It has the kind of materials you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @gopal. Do you know the relevant chapters and sections? Unfortunately I don't have access to the book but I can try google the key words (I will also check the library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This CW is a slight simplification and extension of Michael's answer.)

**Claim**

$Y$ has a decomposition of the required form iff $\text{Cov}(X,Y|Z)$ is constant.

**Proof**

*If*:

Let $U_1=\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$ and $U_2=Y-U_1$. Then $\text{Cov}(U_1, X|Z)=0$.
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(U_2, X) &= \text{Cov}(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|Z], X)\\
                  &= \mathbb{E}[X(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|Z])]\\
                  &= \mathbb{E}[XY-X\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]]\\
                  &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY|Z] - \mathbb{E}[X|Z]\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\text{Cov}(X,Y|Z)]]\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,Y|Z)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X, U_1+U_2|Z)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X, U_2|Z)
\end{align}
$$

*Onlf if:*

Suppose we have a decomposition $Y=U_1+U_2$ satisfying the required conditions. 
$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(U_2, X) &= \text{Cov}(U_2, X|Z)\\
 &= \text{Cov}(Y - U_1, X|Z)\\
                     &= \text{Cov}(X, Y|Z) - \text{Cov}(U_1, X|Z)\\
                     &= \text{Cov}(X, Y|Z),
\end{align}
$$
so $\text{Cov}(X, Y|Z)$ is constant.

**Example**

Suppose $X\sim U(\{-1,0,1\})$, $Y=\mathbf{1}(X=1)$ and $Z=\mathbf{1}(X\neq 0)$, where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function. This example doesn't satisfy the necessary condition, since $\text{Cov}(X,Y|Z)$ depends on $Z$.

Comment: Very nice.  As a minor detail, this assumes $U_1$ is a pure function of $X$, although in general it could also depend on some external randomness.

Comment: Perhaps the general case is obtained if we interpret $U_1(1) \equiv E[U_1|X=1]$ and $U_1(-1)\equiv E[U_1|X=-1]$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I've simplified my answer using that idea.

Comment: I expanded on what you did in my answer below that gives a general necessary condition.

Comment: Elegant.  This was a nice problem.  Very clever thinking up $f(Z)=E[Y|Z]$ for a general sufficient condition.

Comment: @Michael btw. under the assumption Cov$(X,Y|Z)$ since $Y$ is decomposable in this way, by symmetry so is $X$!

Answer (score 2):

Ben Derrett solves this question (he shows it is generally impossible).  Here is a necessary condition for doing what you want:

Claim: A necessary condition is that $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ has no dependence on $Z$.

Proof: Suppose we have $U_1,U_2$ such that $U_1+U_2=Y$ and $Cov(U_1,X|Z)=0$ for all $Z$.  Then $E[U_1X|Z] =E[U_1|Z]E[X|Z]$ and so:

\begin{align} 
Cov(U_2, X|Z) &=Cov(Y-U_1,X|Z) \\
&=E[(Y-U_1)X|Z] - E[Y-U_1|Z]E[X|Z]\\
&=E[YX|Z] - E[U_1X|Z] - E[Y|Z]E[X|Z]+E[U_1|Z]E[X|Z]\\
&=E[YX|Z] - E[Y|Z]E[X|Z]\\
&= Cov(X,Y|Z)
\end{align} 
and hence we require $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ to have no dependence on $Z$.

---

Here is *positive result* about what can be done in this direction:

Given a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$, define $U_1= f(Z)$ for some real-valued function $f(z)$.   Then:

\begin{align}
XU_1 &= Xf(Z) \\
E[XU_1|Z] &= E[X f(Z)|Z] \\
&= f(Z)E[X|Z]\\
&= E[f(Z)|Z] E[X|Z]\\
&= E[U_1|Z]E[X|Z]
\end{align}

and so indeed $Cov(U_1,X|Z) = 0$ for all $Z$. Hence, by the proof of the first claim, it also holds that $Cov(U_2, X|Z) = Cov(X,Y|Z)$.

This holds for all functions $f(z)$.  If $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ does not depend on $Z$, sometimes we can choose $f(z)$ so that $Cov(X,Y|Z)=Cov(U_2, X)$, in which case all of your desired properties hold.

For example, suppose $Cov(X,Y|Z)=b$ for all $Z$. Let $f(z)=az$ for some real number $a$. Thus, $U_1=aZ$, $U_2=Y-aZ$, and we have: 
\begin{align} 
Cov(U_2,X) &= E[X(Y-aZ)] - E[X]E[Y-aZ]\\
&= E[XY] - aE[XZ] - E[X]E[Y]+aE[X]E[Z]\\
&= Cov(X,Y) - aCov(X,Z)
\end{align} 
If $Cov(X,Z) \neq 0$ we can choose $a$ so that the above is equal to $b$, namely: 
$$ a = \frac{Cov(X,Y)-b}{Cov(X,Z)} $$
and all of your desired properties hold.  So a *sufficient* condition is that $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ does not depend on $Z$, and $Cov(X,Z)\neq 0$.

Comment: Very nice! Using the bilinearity of the covariance reduces the proof of necessity to one line. Letting $f(Z)=\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$ shows the condition is also sufficient.

Comment: @BenDerrett and Michael. Thanks for the solutions. This is precisely what I was looking for (sorry for the late reaction by me)... I'm torn to who to give the bounty. Is there a way to split the bounty?

Comment: Try keeping the question open for a bit.  Ben's sufficient condition is not clear to me...I would like to know if the necessary and sufficient conditions can be matched.  You can give the bounty to Ben eventually.

Comment: @BenDerrett are you sure $f(Z)=E[Y|Z]$ is suffficient?  We need to prove $Cov(Y-E[Y|Z], X)=Cov(X,Y|Z)$, which reduces to proving $E[XY] - E[XE[Y|Z]] = E[XY|Z] - E[X|Z]E[Y|Z]$.

Comment: The most general sufficient condition I can currently muster is if $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ does not depend on $Z$, and if there is a function $g(Z)$ such that $Cov(X, g(Z))\neq 0$, in which case we define $U_1=ag(Z)$ for a suitable $a$.

Comment: I think what @BenDerrett is saying is: Assume that Cov$(X,Y|Z)=b$ i.e. doesn't depend on $Z$. Define $U_1=E[Y|Z]$ and $U_2=Y-E[Y|Z]$. Then $Y=U_1+U_2$ with Cov$(X,U_1|Z)=0$ and Cov$(X,U_2|Z)=$Cov$(X,U_2)$.

Comment: @user103828 Yes, but that is exactly what I cannot prove. It reduces to trying to prove $Cov(X, Y-E[Y|Z])=b$.

Comment: Is it not just $Cov(X,U_1|Z)=Cov(X,f(Z)|Z)=0$ and $Cov(X,U_2|Z)=Cov(X,Y-U_1|Z)=Cov(X,Y|Z)-Cov(X,U_1|Z)=Cov(X,Y|Z)$ which is constant by assumption... thanks, fixed the typo just in time. (In your notation $Cov(X,Y-E[Y|Z]|Z)=Cov(X,Y|Z)$ because $E[Y|Z]$ is a function in $Z$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22122/discussion-between-michael-and-user103828).

Comment: Note that saying $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ does not depend on $Z$ is more general than saying $Cov(X,Y|Z)=Cov(X,Y)$.  For example, let $X=Y=Z$ and suppose $Z$ has nonzero variance.  Then $Cov(X,Y|Z)=0$ for all $Z$, but $Cov(X,Y)=Var(Z)\neq 0$.

Comment: @BenDerrett Okay now I agree that your $f(Z)=E[Y|Z]$ works.  How did you come up with that?  _So the necessary and sufficient condition is that $Cov(X,Y|Z)$ does not depend on $Z$_.

Comment: @BenDerrett Oh I see you are online now.  I will read your modified answer.